# Scale a sprite size

Tags: python, pygame

I have sprites running around a simulator.

```
class guys(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("/Users/taiji/Desktop/Sim/images/guys.png")
        self.original_image = self.image
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((50, 30))
        pos = (random.uniform(0,SCREEN_WIDTH), random.uniform(0,300))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(center = pos)
```

I would like to shrink them in size from (50, 30) to (5, 3). Later on I'll have them grow based on energy so I'll change that (5, 3) to something else, but I'm just trying to get the basics down now. I tried this:

```
def grow(sprites):
    for entity in sprites:
        pygame.transform.scale(entity.surf, (5, 3))
```

But they didn't change at all. Can someone help me with this? Do I need to do anything to entity.rect so that collisions are still ok?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

This occurs because `pygame.transform.scale()` does not operate in place. This can be solved by assigning the surface to the function output, like so:

```
entity.surf = pygame.transform.scale(entity.surf, (5, 3))
```

As a note, this method is considered destructive, and thus scaling back up would likely lead to the sprites being unrecognizable. One way to solve this is to save the initial sprite (as it seems you've already done with `self.original_image`) and simply set the new sprite to a scaled version of that original.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting this, sorry (though thank you for the help!)

I changed the code to this:

```
def grow(sprites):
    for entity in sprites:
        entity.surf = pygame.transform.scale(entity.surf, (5, 3))
```

And I made sure it's called on the group, but they're still the same size. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @taijifajin Are you redrawing the scaled surfaces afterwards?

Comment: @taijifajin A PyGame sprite will *always* draw `sprite.image`, so change all occurrences of `sprite.surf` to `sprite.image`.

Comment: @bbnumber2 I have draw as the last function in the main code of the game.

Comment: @Kingsley I just tried that, they flicker back to the normal size sometimes but are otherwise small. Do you know how to stop the flicker? Is their rect size the new, smaller size or do I have to do something with it?